# view.getRight returns width of imageview, not position

Tags: java, android

I have an imageView called iv that is defined in onCreate. In onTouchEvent (not in onCreate, so that isn't the problem), I call

```
int right = iv.getRight();
```

However, this makes "right" equal 118, which is the length of the image. I want it to return the position on the screen, but instead it is returning me the dimensions of the view itself. Can someone explain why this is?

Comment if there is any other relevant code you may need.

Comment: is your imageView has a parent view?

Comment: yes, it is within a linearlayout that is within another linearlayout.

Comment: in this case getRight() will return you position of view reletive to its parent. not it's position on screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getRight()` doesn't return screen position or width.  It returns the position of the right edge relative to its parent view.  Use `view.getLocationOnScreen()` to get the left edge, then add in `view.getWidth()` to find the right.